# Android 8 - How to know what side the Navigation Bar is when going from LANDSCAPE to REVERSE_LANDSCAPE?

Tags: android, navigationbar, android-8.0-oreo

In Android 8, when the phone goes to `LANDSCAPE` the navigation will be on the right side of the screen, and when its in `REVERSE_LANDSCAPE`, it'll be on the left side.
What I did to find out which side of the screen it is on was to have the root `View` of my activity and check it's size and position in these ways:

```
if (rootView.width == deviceScreenWidth) {
    // device is tablet and the navigation bar is at the bottom, or
    // its a samsung device with no navigation bar
} 
else if (rootView.positionOnScreenX == 0) {
    // the navigation bar is at the LEFT side
} 
else {
    // the navigation bar is at the RIGHT side
}
```

But I'm facing a new problem regarding this approach, which is if user goes directly from `LANDSCAPE` to `REVERSE_LANDSCAPE` navigation bar will change location, but the code doesn't run again which causes problems.

Is there any callbacks in android sdk to listen to this rotation? Or is there a better way to know which side of the screen the navigation bar is, without running into this problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this @simmorsal? I'm facing the exact same problem. If you are trying to do it in an activity then you can just read the Insets, but if (like me) you are doing it in a service then that doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke unfortunately no. I ended up redesigning what I wanted to do!

Comment: Understood, thanks @simmorsal for getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Activity#onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) to get a callback when the user rotates their device.

You can checkout these links for more details:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

Comment: This isn't really an answer now. The navigation can be on the left or the right.

On a Nexus 5x with the charger on the left... the nav is on the left. On the Pixel 2 when the charger is on the left - the nav is on the right.